# Android Studio: NullPointerException. getInt from DB

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

i take a Int from DB with this code in a function:

```
 Cursor res = mDBHelper.contr();
    while (res.moveToNext()) {
        percA = res.getInt(1);......
```

After i use this function to animate the number percA:

```
private void startCountAnimation() {
          ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, percA);
    animator.setDuration(1500);
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            percA.setText(animation.getAnimatedValue().toString());
        }
    });
    animator.start();

}
```

But this code doesn't work. The error is:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference.

I try to change the property of variable percA and the property of function but i can't find the problem. Why my variable points to null?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You have NULL value in the database... Use isNull method to check it before using getInt or make constrain on this column.

Comment: @Zoe no, it is not...

Comment: @Selvin yes it is.

Comment: No, it isn't... It is not in his code where npe occurs, also it is not possible to debug it with information from this question.

Comment: @Selvin the object intValue is used on is null. There's no null check before doing that. It is a dupe. If not, there's missing code which makes it off-topic

Comment: No, it isn't... **It is called internally by Cursor.getInt implementation.** And he cannot check if something is null there. Eventually it may be off-topic as there is no full stacktrace, but please, read the question before closing it as npe dupe... As you did FX here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48385221/robolectric-not-handling-getapplicationcontext-correctly-npe fortunately it was reopen. Ive also hate npe in own code questions but some NPE are not in own code and cannot be fixed with given answer.

Answer (score 0):

how much columns did you expect in the result of your result ?
If your waiting for only one column maybe you should getInt(0) and not getInt(1). If your try to retrieve data from a column that doesn't exist you've got a NPE. Just asking ...